# Easiest way to flip a boolean value?

Tags: c++, c, boolean, boolean-logic

I just want to flip a boolean based on what it already is. If it's true - make it false. If it's false - make it true.

Here is my code excerpt:

```
switch(wParam) {

case VK_F11:
  if (flipVal == true) {
     flipVal = false;
  } else {
    flipVal = true;
  }
break;

case VK_F12:
  if (otherVal == true) {
     otherValVal = false;
  } else {
    otherVal = true;
  }
break;

default:
break;
}
```

Answer (score 416, accepted):

You can flip a value like so:

```
myVal = !myVal;
```

so your code would shorten down to:

```
switch(wParam) {
    case VK_F11:
    flipVal = !flipVal;
    break;

    case VK_F12:
    otherVal = !otherVal;
    break;

    default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: Not only this is the easiest, but also the cleanest way.

Comment: the two cases can be merged as they do the same thing.

Comment: Too bad more than half of it is wasted though.. :/

Comment: Is default: break; really necessary? Won't the switch end the same without it?

Comment: Default: break; is unnecessary.

Comment: If you're toggling something long-winded like object1->system1.system2.system3.parameter1 then it can be helpful to have a TOGGLE(a) macro.  This prevents some mistakes and makes it all more readable on narrow screens.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: if the switch is done on a `enum`, compilers will spit warnings if some values don't have a `case` and there's no `default`. Yes it clutters the code. No, you can't avoid it, if you want the code to be portable across compilers, and built with all warnings and warnings-are-errors enabled.

Answer (score 98):

Clearly you need a factory pattern!

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = new KeyFactory();
KeyObj keyObj = keyFactory.getKeyObj(wParam);
keyObj.doStuff();


class VK_F11 extends KeyObj {
   boolean val;
   public void doStuff() {
      val = !val;
   }
}

class VK_F12 extends KeyObj {
   boolean val;
   public void doStuff() {
      val = !val;
   }
}

class KeyFactory {
   public KeyObj getKeyObj(int param) {
      switch(param) {
         case VK_F11:
            return new VK_F11();
         case VK_F12:
            return new VK_F12();
      }
      throw new KeyNotFoundException("Key " + param + " was not found!");
   }
}
```

:D

```
</sarcasm>
```

Comment: We could probably add in the singleton pattern for the factory too.

Comment: @Orm Cause you are an _ORM_? :)

Comment: Note the subtle recommendation to switch to Java!

Comment: Well ... i think we need another major release of C++ for this one, may be C++/51

Comment: Hey guys! I think your approach is not reentrant. You need atomic_bool at least, better a mutex or an event queue. Further, we need an observer-pattern to monitor the state of val.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is amazing or horrible... Probably amazing.  A note to beginners:  Drew is, in fact, being sarcastic.  You should go for a solution that is as simple as possible (but no simpler)... although the factory pattern is very powerful, and you should learn it.  </not sarcasm>

Answer (score 57):

Easiest solution that I found:

```
x ^= true;
```

Comment: `x = !x;` is not only shorter, but also more legible.

Comment: Note that e.g. `longVariableName ^= true;` is clearly shorter than `longVariableName = !longVariableName;` And every programmer should know XOR.

Comment: `a ^= b` means `a = a ^ b`, where `^` means XOR. The notation `a °= b` for `a = a ° b` for any operator `°` is very common amongst C/C++/C# syntax.

Comment: Yes, I know that. It's just that I'm using R for so long that I was thinking about ^ as power function. So ^= would need to have an entirely new meaning... Lol

Comment: Anecdotal, but I recently came across the line `gRackWidget->modules->first().lights[PATTERN1_LIGHT + i].value = !gRackWidget->modules->first().lights[PATTERN1_LIGHT + i].value;` Of course, the cleanest thing to do is to expand it to multiple lines and use temporary variables to store the objects, but `gRackWidget->modules->first().lights[PATTERN1_LIGHT + i].value ^= 1` is much more readable, less error prone, and fewer characters than the original code.

Comment: Additionally, less duplication means less chance for forgetting to update BOTH sides of the equation during rapid development changes / long days/nights of coding.

Comment: @Vortico, anedoctal but it was precisely to avoid a line like that I came here today. I suppose you can say that there is also obfuscation by verbosity.

Comment: IMMO this solution is preferable to `x = !x` also because it prevents copy-paste errors, you do not take any risk of involving another variable by mispelling the right operand (imagine 2 similar name variables, both have a function flipping it, the second function is made copy-pasting the first, and you only remember to change the left operand)

Answer (score 46):

If you know the values are 0 or 1, you could do `flipval ^= 1`.

Comment: Why use a bitwise operator for a logical operation? Smells of needless obfuscation to me.

Comment: @Mark: Sorry. Guess I'm old-fashioned. But it does help if your L-value expression is really long, so you don't have to repeat it. Also, you could say flipval ^= TRUE. Is that better?

Comment: @Mark - see my posting - because sometimes your logical values are stored in bits.  Not everyone wants to waste a whole 8 bits (or more) just for a boolean.

Comment: @Alnitak: You're right in some circumstances. I have seen some people pack bits together to "save space" and act as if the instructions to access them didn't take any space.

Comment: I'm confused as to how this would work... If my value is 0 (false) and I say `myVal ^= 1` wouldn't that be `myVal = 0^1` which is still `0` and if my value is 1 (true) and I say `myVal ^= 1` wouldn't that be `myVal = 1^1` which is still `1`? How does this flip the BOOL value?

Comment: @Albert: `^` is the _exclusive-or_ operator. `0^1` is `1`, and `1^1` is `0`. It's the same as adding if you ignore the carry bit. Or you can think of it as - if either bit is 1, the result is the inverse of the other bit. Or you can think of it as asking the question: Are these two bits different?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey that last way of thinking of it made sense! Are 0 and 1 different? "1" (yes), they are! are 1 and 1 different? "0" (no), the aren't!

Comment: @MikeDunlavey if you're on a device with 4M of Flash for code space, and 3K of SRAM for data space then that is a justified way of acting!

Comment: I vote for this one. Right now, I'm writing a test case, I need to flip a bool and sometimes expressions are really long. Obfuscation is bad, true, but the amount of text on the screen can also be obfuscating, math is easier.

Comment: Also, on embedded systems, 5 lines of comments to explain a line of black magic is sometimes worth it. :)

Answer (score 17):

Just for information - if instead of an integer your required field is a single bit within a larger type, use the 'xor' operator instead:

```
int flags;

int flag_a = 0x01;
int flag_b = 0x02;
int flag_c = 0x04;

/* I want to flip 'flag_b' without touching 'flag_a' or 'flag_c' */
flags ^= flag_b;

/* I want to set 'flag_b' */
flags |= flag_b;

/* I want to clear (or 'reset') 'flag_b' */
flags &= ~flag_b;

/* I want to test 'flag_b' */
bool b_is_set = (flags & flag_b) != 0;
```

Answer (score 12):

Just because my favorite odd ball way to toggle a bool is not listed...

```
bool x = true;
x = x == false;
```

works too.  :)

(yes the `x = !x;` is clearer and easier to read)

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be a free-for-all ... Heh. Here's another varation, which I guess is more in the category "clever" than something I'd recommend for production code:

```
flipVal ^= (wParam == VK_F11);
otherVal ^= (wParam == VK_F12);
```

I guess it's advantages are:

- Very terse
- Does not require branching

And a just as obvious disadvantage is

- Very terse

This is close to @korona's solution using ?: but taken one (small) step further.

Comment: By order of operations, I think you can omit the parenthesis for even more terse. :O

Answer (score 9):

The codegolf'ish solution would be more like:

```
flipVal = (wParam == VK_F11) ? !flipVal : flipVal;
otherVal = (wParam == VK_F12) ? !otherVal : otherVal;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
flipVal ^= 1;
```

same goes for

```
otherVal
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer John T's solution, but if you want to go all code-golfy, your statement logically reduces to this:

```
//if key is down, toggle the boolean, else leave it alone.
flipVal = ((wParam==VK_F11) && !flipVal) || (!(wParam==VK_F11) && flipVal);
if(wParam==VK_F11) Break;

//if key is down, toggle the boolean, else leave it alone.
otherVal = ((wParam==VK_F12) && !otherVal) || (!(wParam==VK_F12) && otherVal);
if(wParam==VK_F12) Break;
```

Comment: Don't you have to check wParam against VK_F11 and VK_F12?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you need a flexible solution that can support types masquerading as boolean. The following allows for that:

```
template<typename T>    bool Flip(const T& t);
```

You can then specialize this for different types that might pretend to be boolean. For example:

```
template<>  bool Flip<bool>(const bool& b)  { return !b; }
template<>  bool Flip<int>(const int& i)    { return !(i == 0); }
```

An example of using this construct:

```
if(Flip(false))  { printf("flipped false\n"); }
if(!Flip(true))  { printf("flipped true\n"); }

if(Flip(0))  { printf("flipped 0\n"); }
if(!Flip(1)) { printf("flipped 1\n"); }
```

No, I'm not serious.

Answer (score 0):

For integers with values of 0 and 1 you can try:

```
value = abs(value - 1);
```

MWE in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        printf("Hello, World!\n");
        int value = 0;
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
                value = abs(value -1);
                printf("%d\n", value);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because I like to question code. I propose that you can also make use of the ternary by doing something like this:

Example:

```
bool flipValue = false;
bool bShouldFlip = true;
flipValue = bShouldFlip ? !flipValue : flipValue;
```

Comment: Haven't tried it but I suspect it will raise the same error.  Will try it later and let you know.

Comment: Just tried it and it passes.  Thanks.
Received a warning that bShouldFlip should be declared const but if I will use Jason Turners best practices template then what can I expect!

Answer (score 0):

I could not get boolean != boolean or any of the variations on it to work without raising a tautological-compare error from clang-tidy.  Rather than disable a warning (why enable warnings if you are going to ignore them!) my solution was to add a small lambda inside the function:

```
auto flip_boolean{ [](bool item) {
  if (item == true) { return false; }
  return true;
} };
```

This not only negated the warning but also, i think, improves the readability as flip_boolean expresses the required behaviour explicitly.  The compiler will probably optimise it away in the end so there is no real need to be frugal with the typing.