# Invert bool if true

Tags: java, boolean

What is the most condense way to invert a boolean if another boolean is true.  In other words, what is the shortest way of writing `condition ? !value : value`, preferably evaluating `value` only once?

Edit: Just so you know, I am passing the result to a method

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: To me it seems that "value = condition?!value:value" is the most condensed form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to flip a boolean value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610916/easiest-way-to-flip-a-boolean-value)

Comment: @gtgaxiola If you're looking for the most condensed form, using a xor is much shorter than using the ternary operator.

Comment: @SajadLfc No, this isn't a duplicate of that. This question has a little more to it.

Comment: @zakinster correct you are!

Comment: @arshajii then, how can i unflag it..?!!

Comment: @SajadLfc I don't think you can; a moderator will simply decline the flag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The shortest way is

```
value ^= condition;
```

Comment: not the best form for passing into a method, but any programmer worth their salt knows that is short-hand for `value = value ^ condition`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: another way is `value = value != condition`

Comment: To clarify, this is the XOR operator.  See the truth table here to understand why this works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Answer (score 6):

All you want is

```
if (condition)
    value = !value;
```

No need to bring the conditional operator in; that would just be unnecessary clutter. The reason this would be preferable over

```
value = condition ? !value : value;
```

is because the above performs an assignment irrespective of `condition`'s value; if `condition` is `false`, we just assign `value` to itself. This works as well, but isn't really what you want logically. You want to invert `value` (i.e. perform an assignment) *if* `condition` is true. I would argue that the the second variant is simply a misuse of the conditional operator. Beyond that, the first variant is certainly more readable and easier to follow.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
value = condition ^ value
```

Not the most readible solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
if(condition)
   value = !value
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you even bother about the short or long even. Prefer more readable code. You can write

```
if (SomeCondition) {
    value = !value;
}
```

Since there is no need for `else` condition, since the `value` is `value` in else.

Answer (score 0):

as your question says '`invert bool if true`'

you should use:

```
 if(statement)
    {

    value=!value;
    }
```

Comment: With `if(statement==true)` you can easy make mistake by writing it like `if(statement=true)`. To avoid this kind of mistakes it is better to use [yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions): `if (true==statement)` or just `if(statement)` since `statement==true` is the same as just `statement`.

Comment: @Pshemo; Like Yoda conditions, I do.

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to have a function or method like this

`boolean invert(boolean condition, boolean value){ return condition != value; }`

In fact:

```
condition value  inversion
t           t      f
t           f      t
f           t      t
f           f      f
```

in the first 2 cases condition is true and inversion is performed, otherwise in the last two cases.