# C: flip integer value as a boolean

Tags: c

I'm looking a way to flip an integer value (8bits) using it as a boolean (0 -> False, 1 -> True).

On many languages you can do `val = !val` to change the value. The only thing I have done is `val = (val == 1) ? 0 : 1`. I don't know if in C can work with a bite value.

It is for an old hardware with a 8bit processor, so the idea of use `boolean` is not possible, and I can't install external libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610916/easiest-way-to-flip-a-boolean-value

Comment: You question is not clear. What do you mean by "flip"? Perhaps negate? C already treats integers as books and. In fact, there is no special Boolean type in C. A zero is interpreted as false, any other value - as true.

Comment: Anyway you can actually do `val = !val` ....

Comment: In C zero is falsy and everything else is truthy. It looks like you want one truthy and everything else falsy. In that case, you can simplify to `val = val != 1;`. Otherwise, `val = !val` works just fine.

Comment: @DyZ [hello, time traveler. Have a nice stay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) :)

Comment: Using just integer calculations, you can do `i = (i-1) * -1` every time you want to flip. A bit verbose though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted one answer, but I may have misread the question.  If you have an integer variable -- it might be `int`, `short int`, or `char` -- and you want to have it cycle back and forth 0, 1, 0, 1 (which you can interpret as false, true, false, true), there are two about equally good ways to do it.  You could do:

```
i = !a;
```

This first way emphasize the "Boolean" nature of the variable.
Or, you could do:

```
i = 1 - i;
```

This second way is purely numeric.

But either way will work perfectly well.  In either case, `i` is guaranteed to alternate 0, 1, 0, 1, ...

You could also use

```
i = i ? 0 : 1;
```

or

```
i = (i == 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Both of these will work, too, but they're basically equivalent to `i = !i`.

In your question you suggested

```
i = (i == 1) ? 0 : 1;
```

This would mostly work, but it looks weird to my eye.  Also it would do the wrong thing if `i` ever ended up containing 2 (or any value other than 0 or 1).

Answer (score 4):

In C a value of 0 is considered "false", and any other (nonzero) value is considered "true".  So one, very explicit way to convert an arbitrary `int` value to an explicitly true-or-false Boolean value is to use the (C99 and later) `bool` type:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int i;
bool b;

b = (i != 0) ? true : false;
```

But since the `!=` operator essentially "returns" a Boolean value, you can also do

```
b = (i != 0);
```

And since the zero/nonzero definition is built in to the language, you can also just do

```
b = i;
```

But you don't have to use type `bool`.  If you have an arbitrary-value int and you want to force it to 0/1 "in place", you have the same sorts of options:

```
i = (i != 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Or

```
i = (i != 0);
```

Or there's another common trick:

```
i = !!i;
```

This last is concise, popular, and somewhat obscure.  It changes zero/nonzero to 1/0 and then back to 0/1.

I've shown these examples using type `int`, but they would all work just as well with `short int` or `char` (i.e. byte).

---

One more thing.  In your question you wrote `val = (val == 1) ? 0 : 1`, but that's basically meaningless.  In C, at least, everything (everything!) follows from whether a value is zero or nonzero.  Explicit comparisons with 1 are almost always a bad idea, if not a downright error.

Comment: This answer assumes your compiler supports C99 features. Not all compilers support C99 features universally and equivalently.

Comment: @AlexReynolds You mean type `bool`?  True, but everything else would work just as well all the way back to C72.  (And 1999 was almost 20 years ago...)

Comment: @AlexReynolds What example non-C99 compiler does not support `bool` in 2018?

Comment: In addition, this answer should add an `#include <stdbool.h>` and the compiler will need to target C99 or greater, with the assumption of support for this feature.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Added mention of `<stdbool.h>`, thanks.

Comment: Also I think I misread the question.  Posting a second answer.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to Summit's answer, you can also do this:

```
#define TRUE ~0U
#define FALSE 0U

#ifndef BOOL
#define BOOL unsigned int;
#endif

int main() {
    BOOL var = TRUE;
    var = ~var; //Negate var and set it to false.
    var = ~var; //Negate var again and set it to true.
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you are using at least C99, then you can change

```
#ifndef BOOL
#define BOOL unsigned int;
#endif
```

to:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef BOOL
#define BOOL uint_fast8_t;
#endif
```

Comment: Non-portable - All bitwise operations on signed types are implementation-defined. Plus it is much less clear than Summit's answer.